# How do I discard a draft review comment on gerrit using API?

Tags: gerrit

How can I discard a draft comment from a specific gerrit review using API, either HTTP (REST) or ssh one.

Note: I am not looking for a "click the web interface" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following endpoint to list the drafts comments of a revision:

```
GET /changes/{change-id}/revisions/{revision-id}/drafts/
```

See more info in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-drafts).

And then use the following endpoint to delete a draft comment:

```
DELETE /changes/{change-id}/revisions/{revision-id}/drafts/{draft-id}
```

See more info in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#delete-draft).